# reflection is visible in cycles render but not in saved image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency, reflection

In my scene I have only two mesh objects: a reflections-only plane and an icosphere. The image renders as expected (pic 1). To be clear, this is not a viewport render. It's a cycles render of a single image.

That's why it so baffling to me that when I save the image as a PNG (pic 2) the reflection vanishes. What in the world could be going on?

RENDER

[image: icosphere with reflection]

SAVED PNG FILE

[image: icosphere]

PLANE MATERIAL

[image: plane reflection-only material]

ICOSPHERE MATERIAL

[image: icosphere material]

RENDER PASSES

[image: render passes]

SCENE

[image: scene]

[image]

Comment: Please don't make your questions depend exclusively on others 
downloading the file, or reading links, just to understanding the 
issue. Please use the [edit] option at the bottom of your question 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how 
you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)
that might help others understand your scene and settings.

Comment: Therein lies the rub, Emir. If I knew what information to include I wouldn't be asking. Nevertheless, I've added pics of the materials, some render settings, and the scene as I've described it. If you have any suggestions for what else to include, please let me know.

Comment: From your images i can assume that your problem is Color Depth, if you are saving in PNG 8 Bits, you will lose a lot of details with that transparent reflection. PNG 16 will probably let you see the reflection a bit, and openEXR 32 Bit will show you the object a lot more. try to save with 32 Bit file and see if that helps

Comment: Have you been found a solution? I have the same problem :(